# Pass bundle from first to third activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to pass my variables as shown in my first activity on button click:

It works fine if I retrieve them on 2nd Activity.But I need to directly pass them to third activity instead of 2nd.

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, Step3Activity.class);
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
  String getploc=txtFromTime.getText().toString();
  String getfrmdate=txtFromTime.getText().toString();
  //Create the bundle
  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
  //Add your data to bundle
  bundle.putString("pickuploc", getploc);  
  bundle.putString("fromdate", getfrmdate);
  //Add the bundle to the intent
  intent.putExtras(bundle);
  //Fire that second activity
  startActivity(intent);
```

And in third acitivity i'm getting them as :

```
 //Get the bundle
 Intent i = getIntent();
 Bundle bundle = i.getExtras();
 /*Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();*/

 //Extract the data…
 String pickuploc = bundle.getString("pickuploc"); 
 String fromdate = bundle.getString("fromdate");
```

Can anyone guide me the right way of passing them to third activity.

Answer (score 1):

In the second activity get the Extras Bundle and set it using putExtras in the intent calling the third Activity.

Or if you want more control copy them manually.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using [shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) as shown.

```
SharedPreferences data = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
data.edit().putString("PickLocation", getploc).commit();
data.edit().putString("FromDate", getfrmdate).commit();
```

and calling it in 3rd Activity as:

```
SharedPreferences data = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
String pickuploc = data.getString("PickLocation",""); 
String fromdate = data.getString("FromDate","");
```

Comment: Take in consideration:
1. SharedPreferences are file based so you shouldn't call commit after each change, get an editor - do changes - commit. don't use this method for parameters that are fast changing as it requires writing and reading from file.
2. Since they are file based they are kept even after the activities are finished - till they are overwritten or deleted.